# Remove or change google maps address in google search result snippet

Tags: google-maps, seo, google-search

On one of my sites I have a google maps pin, address and phone number included in my search result snippet. The problem is that it's the correct address but the phone number is wrong and I can't understand where this come from and how to change it or remove the maps snippet from the result. What I have read is that Google can use information from all over the web to produce a great snippet for my site but in my case it's not so great. Is it possible to change it in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer to this question is that you can modify this information by changing the Google places information or suggest the change to Google.